# How do I disable mapped drives discovery in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drive

I'm setting up a brand new Ubuntu box in a large network. I noticed Ubuntu is picking and configuring both printers and mapped drives automatically and I don't want this to happen. I managed to disable the cups-related service in charge of the printers thanks to one of the answers here, but I haven't been able to do the same for the mapped drives. Could you help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I stopped and disabled the cups service with 'sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed'. But that's only for the printers.

Comment: Yes and I asked what you have done with the drives.

Comment: In the Thunar settings, under Advanced > Removable drives and media, I unchecked all options regarding mounting drives when plugged. The problem is that they still appear when I click on 'network', meaning it is still detecting them. I want them to NOT be discovered at all as this slows down the system.